# MQL5 - How do I get MA on RSI similar to Trading View?

Tags: mql5

I am trying my hands out on getting MA on RSI. This is the screenshot on Tradingview. I love to get the similar setup on MQL5. Can anyone point me in the right direction.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is quite straight forward. Add the RSI indicator to the chart as normal. Then drag the MA indicator to the RSI window, in the `Parameters` tab of the settings, choose `Previous Indicator's Data` for `Apply to`.

[image]